# Bootstrapv4.0.0-beta - Carousel Controls not working

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-4

I cannot get the Carousel Controls to work in Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta. Kind of strange as the Indicators work properly.

Anybody with the same problem? Bellow is the code for the Carousel implementation.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    <div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="view hm-black-light">
                    <!-- CONTENT -->
                    <div class="full-bg-img"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption overlay">
                    <div class="flex-center animated fadeIn">
                        <!-- DETAIL -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="view hm-black-light">
                    <!-- CONTENT -->
                    <div class="full-bg-img"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption overlay">
                    <div class="flex-center animated fadeIn">
                        <!-- DETAIL -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Controls-->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#my-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#my-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems to work correctly with `4.0.0-beta.2`.

Comment: Hi @dferenc

Not for me. If you just use a standard bootstrap v4 theme maybe. I added some plugins and some is definitely ruining it.

Any known compatibility issues with the ibs bellow? How can I debug this?

Thx!


`<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/scrollreveal/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It's hard to tell anything based on that. In order to debug, I would remove all other js from the page and add them back one-by-one while checking the functionality. That should take you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here. All I did is to copy these plugins from the Bootstrap's Website. Controls are working properly now.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```